# PROLOG return size of the smallest generated list

Tags: list, prolog, size, min, predicate

I have a predicate that generates multiple lists in a single query.

Out of all the generated lists, is it possible to find the list(s) with the smallest size and store/return the value of that size? E.g.

```
?- genList(List).

List = [1,2,3,4,5] ;
List = [6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13] ;
List = [14,15,16,17,18,19] ;
List = [20,21] ;
...
```

Here the smallest list is `[20,21]` with the size of `2`.

Ideally I would like a predicate that will return the value `2`.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Using the standard `setof/3` predicate and the de facto standard predicate `length/2`, try:

```
?- setof(List, gen_list(List), [Smaller| _]), length(Smaller, Length).
```

Maybe it's possible to modify the `gen_list/1` predicate to also return the length of the generated list? That could be more efficient.